# Focus on first form element if it the types Text, Password or dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to write some jQuery to focus on the first form element, if it is a Textbox, Password type or dropdown menu.

```
      var Text = $('#pagebody').find('input:text:visible:first')
      var Pass = $('#pagebody').find('input:password:visible:first')
      var Select = $('#pagebody').find('select:visible:first')

      if(Text)
      {
        Text.focus();
      }
      else if(Pass)
      {
        Pass.focus();
      }
      else
      {
        Select.focus();
      }
```

I can't get it to focus on anything passed in the first query of the if statement and I'm not 100% sure why.

**I was just wondering, how would I get it to select the first form element, if it's a text, password or dropdown?**

**and if there is a text and password how to select the first one of them?**

Comment: put space between else and if from elseif.

Comment: Also you logic does not select the first. It selects the first Text if found regardless of other fields on the page, then pass regardless of selects, then select if no text or pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("#pagebody").find('input[type=text],input[type=password],select')
              .filter(':visible:first').focus();
```

Comment: Funny. 1 second apart from another 26k Repper

Comment: This one is however the most elegant :)

Comment: rep's 503, but the answer's the same. :D

Comment: I'd have to disagree there. Mine solution is short, readable, and dripping with awesomesauce.

Answer (score 1):

just select all types of elements at once and take the first hit of the complete list:

```
var element= $('#pagebody').find('input:text:visible, input:password:visible, select:visible').first();
if(element){
  element.focus();
}
```